# How to make that only one radio button can be selected in a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I am implementing a table in an aspx page using repeater, the table is shown correctly.

In every row of the table I want to add a radio button ( a radio button is selected, means that row is selected), when I execute my program the page showed is the following:

[image]

The problem is as you can see in the image is that many radio buttons can be selected at the same time, my purpose is to allow the user to select only one row (one radio button) if a radio button is checked the other shoul be unchekced automatically.

here is my code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DotNetRepeater.aspx.cs" Inherits="DotNetRepeater.DotNetRepeater" %>


<script type = "text/javascript">
    function RadioCheck(rb) {
        var gv = document.getElementById("<%=rptCustomers.ClientID%>");
        var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");

        var row = rb.parentNode.parentNode;
        for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
            if (rbs[i].type == "radio") {
                if (rbs[i].checked && rbs[i] != rb) {
                    rbs[i].checked = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        table
        {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-collapse: collapse; 
           background-color: #00FF00 ;

        }
        table th
        {
            background-color: #FF0000;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        table th, table td
        {
            padding: 5px;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        form {
             width: 100%;
             text-align: center;
            height: 371px;
        }
        #Button1 {
             background-color: yellow;
             font-size: 15pt;

            top: 355px;
            left: 800px;
        }
        /*#SelectRadio1{
            left: 461px;*/
        /*}*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptCustomers_ItemCommand">

        <HeaderTemplate>

            <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1"  align="center"; >

                <tr>
                       <th scope="col" style="background-color:white">

                    </th>

                    <th scope="col" style="width: 80px">
                        Name             
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 120px">
                        CountryRegionCode
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 100px">
                        Group
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 100px">
                        SalesYTD
                    </th>
                </tr>

        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr >
                <td style="background-color:white">                    
                     <asp:RadioButton id="Radio1" Checked="False" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" />            
                </td>
                <td>                    
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />                     
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCountryRegionCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CountryRegionCode") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Group") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SalesYTD") %>' />
                </td>

            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" Width="82px" />
    </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I add to the aspx code or to the code behind to make that only one radio button can be selected ?

Any help please ?

Comment: All your radio button shouldn't have the same id. I think that's why merely can be checked.

Comment: @gagro checkboxes suggest "multiple selection", while the OP wants "single selection", for which radiobuttons are the correct choice.

Comment: That "unchecking of other radiobuttons" is basic functionality of radiobuttons. You did set the required GroupName correctly. No client-side or server-side code should be needed for the unchecking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by giving your table an unique ID (a Repeater does not generate a html element which has it's ID, so ClientID is of no use)

```
<table id="rptCustomers" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" align="center">
```

Now you can reference that table in the following jQuery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#rptCustomers input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        $('#rptCustomers input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
            $(this).prop("checked", "");
        });
        $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
    });
</script>
```

It basically loops all the radio buttons within that table and unchecks them. Then it re-enables the one that was clicked.

> For this to work you need jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for you help but I tried the code and I got the error:   `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: OK, it works now, please edit your answer adding that jquery must be included.

Comment: If your checkboxes are being written out as asp:RadioButtons, remember to add the proper $(document).ready(function () {  ...rest of code here...  }); otherwise the code won't fire

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, it can be approached in two ways. One is client side using javascript (something like @VDWWD's answer) and other is server side as below.

```
//Repeater ItemTemplate RadioButton
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged"/>


//Code Behind
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Uncheck all RadioButtons of the rptCustomer
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptCustomer.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ((RadioButton)item.FindControl("RadioButton1")).Checked = false;
    }
}
//After foreach loop, set current selected checkbox checked
(sender as RadioButton).Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `everity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Control' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  
` 





In the line:  `(RadioButton)item.FindControl("RadioButton1").Checked = false;` inside the IF

Comment: @rainman I have already modified the code. Please try again and let me know if still got error.